# Table-valued parameters: Use of column default of the user-defined table type

Tags: c#, sql

I am passing a table-valued parameter to a stored procedure. ([Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)). I use an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` instance as the parameter.

For a column, I want some records to use a value set explicitly on the `SqlDataRecord` and for other records, I want to use the column default defined by the corresponding user-defined table type.

However, that seems like a mix which can't be achieved, even though the `SqlMetaData.UserServerDefault` property looked like the answer at first glance.

My first problem was that with `UserServerDefault=true`, the column default of the table type is always used, even when a value is set explicitly on the `SqlDataRecord`. I tried to address this by not reusing the same `SqlMetaData[]` instance across all records, but varied the value of `UserServerDefault` as needed. This led to the second problem: The `SqlMetaData[]` of the first record (or at least its value of `UserServerDefault`) seems to be used for all subsequent records.

Code sample to illustrate:

```
// The user-defined table has a single int column, 'MyInt', with some default.

var recordWithExplicitValue = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("MyInt",  SqlDbType.Int, useServerDefault: false, ..));
recordWithExplicitValue.SetValue(ordinal: 0, value: 123);

var recordWithServerDefault = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("MyInt",  SqlDbType.Int, useServerDefault: true, ..));

IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> recordsA = new [] { recordWithExplicitValue, recordWithServerDefault };
IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> recordsB = new [] { recordWithServerDefault, recordWithExplicitValue };

// The following produces the rows (123), (NULL) when transferred to the TVP:
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("..", recordsA));

// The following produces the rows (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT):
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("..", recordsB));
```

I want the rows `(123), (DEFAULT)`. Can that be achieved? Are my observations incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried to profile the sql generated by your code with a MS SSMS profiler ?

Comment: @Serg, I have now. It generates statements like:
`declare @p1 dbo.MyUDT
insert into @p1 values(123)
insert into @p1 values(NULL)
`
or
`declare @p1 dbo.MyUDT
insert into @p1 values(default)
insert into @p1 values(default)`
(with line breaks ofc)

Comment: I see no direct explanation in the manuals but looks like  you are right, only `SqlMetaData` of the first record in a `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` matters